# TFS continuous integration with phonegap build

Tags: cordova

I am using TFS 2013 for cordova mobile project as a repository.Does anybody help me to **automate** iOS and Android builds using **TFS** and Adobe's **Phonegap Build**?

Thanks In Adavance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, what about Telerik??

Check out the links..

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d486edc5-aae3-4ad9-84c1-578efc0a32ed

http://www.telerik.com/teampulse/tfs

http://www.telerik.com/appbuilder/visual-studio-extension

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Krizte but I am not using visual studio and I am using webstorm and updating project files to TFS repository.So is there any bridge which pulls the projct files from TFS and chain those with Adobe's "Phonegap build" to have a automation for build that's what I am wondering.